# Check if $slot is empty in laravel blade component

Tags: laravel, conditional-statements, laravel-blade

I have a component that outputs the $slot. But I want to do something like:

**Component**

```
<x-alert></x-alert>
```

```
<div>
@if ($slot)
    {{ $slot }}
@else
    No available content
@endif
</div>
```

Comment: what is the problem with this code exactly ?

Comment: It always runs the if condition rather than the else one, even when I don't add any items to it.

Comment: what is the type of the variable $slot ? is it an array ?

Comment: Not suer, it's basically any content that I type between the opening and closing tags of the component.

Answer (score 23):

`$slot` is an instance of the `Illuminate\Support\HtmlString` class. So you can use the `isNotEmpty` method:

```
<div>
@if ($slot->isNotEmpty())
    {{ $slot }}
@else
    No available content
@endif
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

the variable `$slot` in laravel components is prepared as Object of type `Illuminate\Support\HtmlString`
so it need to be checked like this  :

```
<div>
@if(strlen($slot->toHtml()) != 0)
    {{$slot}}
@else
    slot is empty
@endif
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this :

```
<div>
@if (isset($slot) && $slot != null )
    {{ $slot }}
@else
    No available content
@endif
</div>
```